# How to delete all letters before semicolon in python?The

Tags: python, string

The string:

> "Jack;10;20;30\n Omar;20,24,25\n Carl;30;30;30\n"

How do I delete using map or filter all names from a string?

```
str = filter( x.isdigit() , for x str)
```

But it does not seem to work properly.

Comment: So you want only the numbers?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, hi again sir, yes, I can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

How about just using split:

```
str = "Jack;10;20;30\n Omar;20,24,25\n Carl;30;30;30\n"
output_list = [line.split(";")[1:] for line in str.split("\n")]
output = [";".join(line) for line in output_list]
>>>['10;20;30', '20,24,25', '30;30;30', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` the string, slice the resulting list, and then re-`join` the sliced list into a string using the same delimiter:

```
s = "Jack;10;20;30\n Omar;20,24,25\n Carl;30;30;30\n"
print('\n'.join(';'.join(l.split(';')[1:]) for l in s.splitlines()))
```

This outputs:

```
10;20;30
20,24,25
30;30;30
```

Answer (score 0):

In your exact case you can use python's built-in `re` and list comprehension.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Jack;10;20;30\n Omar;20,24,25\n Carl;30;30;30\n"
>>> [number for number in re.split(';|,| |\n|', text) if number.isdigit()]
['10', '20', '30', '20', '24', '25', '30', '30', '30']
```

`re.split` splits string by `;`, `,`,  and `\n`

List comprehension creates lists of elements that are numbers.